# Get Unique records in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a **dataframe df** as mentioned below:

```
**customers**   **product**   **val_id**  **rule_name**  **rule_id** **priority**
     1               A            1           ABC            123         1
     3               Z            r           ERF            789         2
     2               B            X           ABC            123         2
     2               B            X           DEF            456         3
     1               A            1           DEF            456         2
```

I want to create a new **dataframe df2**, which will have only unique **customer ids**, but as **rule_name** and **rule_id** columns are different for same customer in data, so I want to pick those records which has highest priority for the same **customer**, so my final outcome should be:

```
 **customers**   **product**   **val_id**  **rule_name**  **rule_id** **priority**
         1               A            1           ABC            123         1
         3               Z            r           ERF            789         2
         2               B            X           ABC            123         2
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve it using Spark scala. Any help will be appericiated.

Answer (score 4):

You basically want to select rows with extreme values in a column. This is a really common issue, so there's even a whole tag [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). Also see this question [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) which has a nice answer.

Here's an example for your specific case.

*Note that this could select multiple rows for a customer, **if** there are multiple rows for that customer with the same (minimum) priority value.*

This example is in `pyspark`, but it should be straightforward to translate to `Scala`

```
# find best priority for each customer. this DF has only two columns.
cusPriDF = df.groupBy("customers").agg( F.min(df["priority"]).alias("priority") )
# now join back to choose only those rows and get all columns back
bestRowsDF = df.join(cusPriDF, on=["customers","priority"], how="inner")
```

Answer (score 0):

To create **df2** you have to first order **df** by **priority** and then find unique customers by **id**. Like this:

```
val columns = df.schema.map(_.name).filterNot(_ == "customers").map(col => first(col).as(col))

val df2 = df.orderBy("priority").groupBy("customers").agg(columns.head, columns.tail:_*).show
```

It would give you expected output:

```
+----------+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------+
| customers| product| val_id| rule_name| rule_id| priority|
+----------+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------+
|         1|       A|      1|       ABC|     123|        1|
|         3|       Z|      r|       ERF|     789|        2|
|         2|       B|      X|       ABC|     123|        2|
+----------+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Corey beat me to it, but here's the Scala version:

```
val df = Seq(
(1,"A","1","ABC",123,1),
(3,"Z","r","ERF",789,2),
(2,"B","X","ABC",123,2),
(2,"B","X","DEF",456,3),
(1,"A","1","DEF",456,2)).toDF("customers","product","val_id","rule_name","rule_id","priority")
val priorities = df.groupBy("customers").agg( min(df.col("priority")).alias("priority"))
val top_rows = df.join(priorities, Seq("customers","priority"), "inner")

+---------+--------+-------+------+---------+-------+
|customers|priority|product|val_id|rule_name|rule_id|
+---------+--------+-------+------+---------+-------+
|        1|       1|      A|     1|      ABC|    123|
|        3|       2|      Z|     r|      ERF|    789|
|        2|       2|      B|     X|      ABC|    123|
+---------+--------+-------+------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `min` `aggregation` on `priority` column `grouping` the `dataframe` by `customers` and then `inner join` the `original dataframe` with the `aggregated dataframe` and `select` the required columns.

```
val aggregatedDF = dataframe.groupBy("customers").agg(max("priority").as("priority_1"))
      .withColumnRenamed("customers", "customers_1")

    val finalDF = dataframe.join(aggregatedDF, dataframe("customers") === aggregatedDF("customers_1") && dataframe("priority") === aggregatedDF("priority_1"))
    finalDF.select("customers",   "product",   "val_id",  "rule_name",  "rule_id", "priority").show
```

you should have the desired result